# renewenvironment document

Tags: environments

To write my thesis I have to use a .cls provided by the faculty. In there, there is the following command:

```
\let\@altdoc=\document
\let\end@altdoc=\enddocument
\renewenvironment{document}{
\begin{@altdoc}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.2}
\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt
}
{\end{@altdoc}}
```

As far as I can tell, this is syntactically correct. However, when compiling, it gives this:

`! LaTeX Error: \begin{altdoc} on input line 79 ended by \end{document}.`

And I have no clue why. Any ideas?

Comment: document/end document is not a normal environment in latex and the class is breaking it. It shouldn't do this, but use the provided hooks instead to add its code at begin document.

Comment: Complain fiercely: nobody can compile documents with that class without getting the error. The instruction `\AtBeginDocument` has been in LaTeX for 25+ years. And those settings to `\baselinestretch` and `\baselineskip` are really silly.